# Entity Framework: Set nullable to false, but type is still nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, visual-studio-2012

This question relates to a new class library project created in Visual Studio 2012.

I have added a SQL Server view to my entity framework model.

In the properties of the `PromisedDate` column, I have changed Nullable from `(None)` to `False` as there will never be a null value returned in this column. I have double-checked there are no null values with a select statement.

[image: Screenshot of edmx showing nullable set to false]

However, even after a save, closing all open tabs in Visual Studio and doing a full clean and rebuild of the solution, `PromisedDate` is still a `DateTime?` and I have to keep using `.Value` in code to get the value of it.

It's frustrating, what am I doing wrong?!

Here is a screenshot of the generated .CS file:

[image: Screenshot of generated class showing still nullable]

Comment: Did you save the changes to the designer file?

Comment: @AndyB - Yes, everything is fully saved.

Comment: @Pawel Could you kindly explain what you mean and how to do it?

Comment: @bgs264 I've posted an answer on how to generate the entities and database again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the following steps.

1) Save designer file and generate your database from designer
2) Click on Context file and Code Generation file(T4) and click run custom tool.
3) make sure you save the file again, an * will appear after you generate the database.

Comment: Hi there, thanks! For future searchers, step 1 was not necessary. All that was necessary was steps 2 and 3.

Comment: More info: http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update.html#.UI5oEcUxoWA