# How to set entity framework 4.5 to never set any property as Nullable

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, nullable

The one feature that I cannot stand with-in the Entity framework is where the complex Result object sets some properties as Nullable.

Is there a global setting to where that Nullable property is never set to yes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that even if you get the property `Nullable` to be `False`, that it will still generate a `Nullable` version of your object.

Check out the accepted answer of [Entity Framework: Set nullable to false, but type is still nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070683/entity-framework-set-nullable-to-false-but-type-is-still-nullable).

Also, read [How to manually update your Entity Framework model classes when they get out of sync with your database](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/08/entity-framework-manual-update.html#.UhqMJpLVDT9) for a description of how to use the `Run Custom Tool` option to run a T4 template after your model has been generated.