# EF Database First - nullable types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a stored procedure which using in EF and for some of the fields it creates nullable (in complex type).

```
public partial class usp_MySp{    
    public Nullable<bool> Enabled { get; set; }
}
```

But in SP, it will never return `NULL` even the Table allow null to Enabled field

```
SELECT ISNULL(Enabled,0) as Enabled
FROM Table
```

Is there anyway to get around this

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434409/how-to-set-entity-framework-4-5-to-never-set-any-property-as-nullable

Comment: @SomeUser: I saw this but it ask to generate database from designer.

Comment: Maybe this answer and it's first comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/13101113/6248956