# How can I prevent Entity Framework from making a property nullable?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

There might be some nuance to this question since [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070683/entity-framework-set-nullable-to-false-but-type-is-still-nullable) describe a similar problem, but their suggestions don't seem to work in our project. The project uses Entity Framework 6.1 and a database first design pattern and the T4 code generation strategy. We have a number of views that generate calculated values that we know will always have a default value, but Entity Framework keeps changing the properties to `Nullable` manually updating the properties works, but as soon as the EDMX is updated it reverts back to `Nullable`.

Is there a way to force Entity Framework to not default to `Nullable` properties? Ideally this is a pattern we can keep following since we use a number of views and constantly needing to update properties is quite tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to ensure that the view reports as being `not null` from SQL Server at which point Entity Framework will not default to `Nullable`. This can be done by [forcing the view column to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326813/how-to-make-a-view-column-not-null) `not null`. Briefly,

```
SELECT CASE Status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS HasStatus  
FROM dbo.Product
```

Will map the `HasStatus` column to `int, null`. However,

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(CASE Status WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS HasStatus  
FROM dbo.Product
```

Will map the `HasStatus` column to `int, not null`.

Comment: Entity Framework (v6.4) recognized the proprietary T-SQL `ISNULL()` function as returning a non-nullable value but had a bug that failed to recognize it when the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` function is used. This caused many wasted days to figure out.